# How do I change the language of moment.js?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am trying to change the language of the date which is being set by moment.js. The default one is English, but I want to set the German language. These is what I tried:

```
var now = moment().format("LLL").lang("de");
```

It’s giving `NaN`.

```
var now = moment("de").format("LLL");
```

This isn’t even reacting.

```
var now = moment().format("LLL", "de");
```

No change: this is still producing a result in English.

How is this possible?

Comment: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/changing-language/

Comment: https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/2962#issuecomment-1116439746

Answer (score 426, accepted):

You need moment.lang (**WARNING**: `lang()` is deprecated since moment `2.8.0`, use `locale()` instead):

```
moment.lang("de").format('LLL');
```

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/

---

As of v2.8.1, `moment.locale('de')` sets the localization, but does not return a `moment`. Some examples:

```
var march = moment('2017-03')
console.log(march.format('MMMM')) // 'March'

moment.locale('de') // returns the new locale, in this case 'de'
console.log(march.format('MMMM')) // 'March' still, since the instance was before the locale was set

var deMarch = moment('2017-03')
console.log(deMarch.format('MMMM')) // 'März'

// You can, however, change just the locale of a specific moment
march.locale('es')
console.log(march.format('MMMM')) // 'Marzo'
```

In summation, calling `locale` on the global `moment` sets the locale for all future `moment` instances, but does not return an instance of `moment`. Calling `locale` on an instance, sets it for that instance AND returns that instance.

Also, as Shiv said in the comments, make sure you use "moment-with-locales.min.js" and not "moment.min.js", otherwise it won't work.

Comment: In the docs, you can create language specific instances of moment by doing that. If you format first, the language won't process. Alternatively, you could do something like `var deMoment = moment(); deMoment.lang('de')` and reuse `deMoment` instead of moment throughout your script.

Comment: If you use "moment.min.js" it won't work; you need 
"moment-with-locales.min.js"

Comment: update: `Deprecation warning: moment().lang() is deprecated. Instead, use moment().localeData() to get the language configuration. Use moment().locale() to change languages.
Arguments: fr`

Comment: If you use browserify, according to the official docs, there is a bug that prevents locale form being loaded. Fortunately, a workaround is also provided, see: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/use-it/browserify/. I was stuck with this myself and it worked!

Comment: with 2.12.0 I get `Uncaught TypeError: moment.locale(...).format is not a function(…)`

Comment: me too: moment.locale(...).format is not a function(…)

Comment: this answer is wrong in 2017, look at @apadana answer

Comment: Must include the locale files, otherwise it will not work.The locale files can use the cdn from here: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/moment.js

Comment: you need to import the wanted language other wise this wont work: 
`import moment from 'moment';
import localization from 'moment/locale/de'`

`moment().locale("de", localization).format('LLL')`

Comment: import moment from 'moment/min/moment-with-locales';

Comment: you can use this  **'Moment.locale('tr')' ** in useeffect func and you must import this **moment/min/moment-with-locales** and where ever can call

Comment: Then you need to import moment. `import * as moment from 'moment'`

Comment: hi, do this work also on hole application setting as in app.module.ts? thank you

Comment: Is there a less convoluted way of using locale than what @Abdelouahab suggested? That's the only way I got it to work but it looks like it could be easier.

Answer (score 395):

I had to import also the language:

```
import moment from 'moment'
import 'moment/locale/es'  // without this line it didn't work
moment.locale('es')
```

Then use moment like you normally would

```
console.log(moment(date).fromNow())
```

Comment: Your answer more helpful than other because you've mentioned about `import 'moment/locale/es'`

Comment: Yes this is the correct answer... thanks, I was pulling my hair out wondering why it wasn't working. But this is a real pain having to import for any language type that might be used. There has to be a better way.

Comment: according to the documentation if someone wants all the locales to be included then he/she can use this `require("moment/min/locales.min");` or using import `import 'moment/min/locales.min'`

Comment: how`moment/locale/es` can be used  with i18next lib ?

Comment: Use `import 'moment/min/locales';` for all the languages.

Comment: The fact that you have to import the locale is mentioned here: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/use-it/typescript/.

No mention of it anywhere in the localization section (https://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/) where you would normally look for info about locales.

This is how we waste our time trying to understand why our code isn't working when doing exactly like the documentation says. I've noticed the same problem across the board (Material, PrimeNG), it seems everyone is incapable of properly documenting how their library works.

Answer (score 57):

### Fastest method: Install with Bower

I just installed moment with bower and linked `de.js` as javascript resource in my html project.

`bower install moment --save`

You can also manually download the `moment.js` and `de.js`.

### Link 'de.js' in your project

Linking the `de.js` in my main project file automatically changed the locale for all accesses to the moment class and its methods.

There will be  **no need anymore** to do a `moment.locale("de").` or
`moment.lang("de").`  in the source code.

Just link your desired locale like this:

```
<script src="/bower_components/moment/moment.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/moment/locale/de.js"></script>
```

Or you can link the libraries without the `bower_components` path, if you downloaded moment.js 1990ies-style via right-click, which still works fine in most scenarios.

Comment: This should be the correct answer. Just link the desired local with `<script src="/bower_components/moment/locale/de.js"></script>`.It works for me right now.

Comment: "There will be no need anymore to do a moment.locale("de"). or moment.lang("de"). in the source code.". I think this is still useful for dynamic apps that change the locale. Like you can theoretically change the locale in my app via a lang/country dropdown in my angular app and then moment should change formats dynamically which I would do I think with moment.locale($lang)

Comment: Sure, but you still need to load the javascript file in your index.html in my tests. This is still an issue in May 2017, maybe moment should include this in their docs.

Answer (score 44):

With momentjs 2.8+, do the following:

```
moment.locale("de").format('LLL');
```

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/

Comment: It *should* work; can you provide an example of where it doesn't work, also how are you using moment (did you install it via npm, etc)?

Comment: With recent moments (I tested in 2.18.1) use this:   moment.locale("de");
  var m = moment().format("LLL")

Comment: apadana is right: you set locale with `moment.locale('de')`, and you create a new object representing the date of now by `moment()` (note the parenthesis) and then `format('LLL')` it. The parenthesis is important. Tested in 2.20. Also, remember to use `moment-with-locale.js` and if necessary, change the name to be `moment.js`. Django just refuse to load `moment-with-locale.js` in my case.

Comment: if this one is not working, try this one : 
`moment().locale('de').format('LLL');`

Comment: This one is coorect, just don't forget to import te locale you want to use (cfr. Agu Dondo's answer).

Answer (score 23):

After struggling, this worked for me for `moment` v2.26.0:

```
import React from "react";
import moment from "moment";
import frLocale from "moment/locale/fr";
import esLocale from "moment/locale/es";

export default function App() {
  moment.locale('fr', [frLocale, esLocale]) // can pass in 'en', 'fr', or 'es'
  
  let x = moment("2020-01-01 00:00:01");
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {x.format("LLL")}
      <br />
      {x.fromNow()}
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can pass in `en`, `fr` or `es`. If you wanted another language, you'd have to import the locale and add it to the array.

If you only need to support one language it is a bit simpler:

```
import React from "react";
import moment from "moment";
import "moment/locale/fr"; //always use French

export default function App() {  
  let x = moment("2020-01-01 00:00:01");
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {x.format("LLL")}
      <br />
      {x.fromNow()}
    </div>
  );
}
```

-- UPDATE --

In one case, importing all the locale files like above would resort in the *last imported locale* always being used (i.e. "es" in the above example), even though I was setting it to "fr".  The solution that seems to work is:

```
import moment from 'moment';
import 'moment/min/locales';

...

moment.locale('fr');
```

Answer (score 19):

end 2017 / 2018: the anothers answers have too much old code to edit, so here my alternative clean answer:

with require

```
let moment = require('moment');
require('moment/locale/fr.js');
// or if you want to include all locales:
require("moment/min/locales.min");
```

with imports

```
import moment from 'moment';
import 'moment/locale/fr';
// or if you want to include all locales:
require("moment/min/locales.min");
```

Use:

```
moment.locale('fr');
moment().format('D MMM YY');  // Correct, set default global format 
// moment.locale('fr').format('D MMM YY') //Wrong old versions for global default format
```

with timezone

*require:

```
require('moment-range');
require('moment-timezone');
```

*import:

```
import 'moment-range';
import 'moment-timezone';
```

use zones:

```
const newYork    = moment.tz("2014-06-01 12:00", "America/New_York");
const losAngeles = newYork.clone().tz("America/Los_Angeles");
const london     = newYork.clone().tz("Europe/London");
```

function to format date

```
const ISOtoDate = function (dateString, format='') {

 // if date is not string use conversion:
 // value.toLocaleDateString() +' '+ value.toLocaleTimeString();

  if ( !dateString ) {
    return '';
  }

  if (format ) {
    return moment(dateString).format(format);
  } else  {
    return moment(dateString);  // It will use default global format
  }  
};
```

Comment: The only thing worked for me was change moment import to:
`import moment from 'moment/min/moment-with-locales';`

Comment: @leojnxs yes, if you want to include all locales, but it's possible to work only with one or more specific locales doing a import for every language

Answer (score 15):

You'd need to add `moment.lang(navigator.language)` in your script.

And must also add each country locale you want to display in : for example for GB or FR, you need to add that locale format in moment.js library. An example of such format is available in momentjs documentation. If you don't add this format in moment.js then it'd ALWAYS pick up US locale as that's the only one that I currently see.

Comment: what if their browser is in 'en' and they are reading in 'es' then it will only show the the time in 'en'

Answer (score 7):

FOR METEOR USERS:

**moment** locales are not installed by default in meteor, you only get the 'en' locale with the default installation.

So you use the code as shown correctly in other answers:

```
moment.locale('it').format('LLL');
```

but it will remain in english until you install the locale you need.

There is a nice, clean way of adding individual locales for **moment** in meteor (supplied by *rzymek*).

Install the **moment** package in the usual meteor way with:

```
meteor add rzymek:moment
```

Then just add the locales that you need, e.g. for italian:

```
meteor add rzymek:moment-locale-it
```

Or if you really want to add all available locales (adds about 30k to your page):

```
meteor add rzymek:moment-locales
```

Comment: @AntonAL Good thing you sent me your comment, I've just noticed that the question wasn't actually for meteor. However my answer's pretty useful I reckon. I've edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks! Added `rzymek:moment-locale-de` and it worked :)

Answer (score 7):

With moment 2.18.1 and onward:

```
  moment.locale("de");
  var m = moment().format("LLL")
```

Comment: Must include the locale files, otherwise it will not work.

Comment: This was already mentioned as not working unless the associated specific moment locale module was imported as well.

Comment: @Maniaque I didn't install nothing special just npm install --save moment and it works fine

Answer (score 5):

This one just works by auto detecting the current user location.

```js
import moment from "moment/min/moment-with-locales";

// Then use it as you always do. 
moment(yourDate).format("MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm a")
```

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure what changed but importing the language file like this worked for me

```
import 'moment/src/locale/fr';
moment.locale('fr')
```

Notice the src in the import statement

Comment: You missed single quote```('fr)```  -> ```('fr')```

Comment: Thanks. Added the missing single quote.ss

Answer (score 4):

Change the moment js language as per Version

**Version: 2.8+**

moment.locale('hi');

**Version: 2.5.1**

moment.lang('hi');

Answer (score 4):

work fine like that: `return moment(status.created_at).locale('es').fromNow();`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 3):

for **momentjs 2.12+**, do the following:

```
moment.updateLocale('de');
```

Also note that you must use `moment.updateLocale(localeName, config)` to change an existing locale. `moment.defineLocale(localeName, config)` should only be used for creating a new locale.

Answer (score 3):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>MomentJS</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="moment.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="locale/ne.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            moment.locale('en'); // default the locale to English
            var localLocale = moment();

            moment.locale('ne'); // change the global locale to Nepalese
            var ne1 = localLocale.format('LLLL');
            var ne2 = moment().format('LLLL');

            $('.ne1').text(ne1);
            $('.ne2').text(ne2);
        });
    </script>
    <p class="ne1"></p>
    <p class="ne2"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

[Demo](http://www.rampukar.xyz/2016/06/momentjs-changing-locales-locally.html)

Answer (score 3):

As I was using webpack with gulp and friends ([this generator](https://github.com/Swiip/generator-gulp-angular) set up everything for me)  I had to make a change to the bower.json file. I had to override the default import for the moment package and select the file that comes with all the languages:

```
"overrides": {
  "moment": {
    "main": [
        "min/moment-with-locales.min.js"
    ]
  }
}
```

This is my full bower.json file:

```
{
  "name": "html5",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular-animate": "~1.4.2",
    "angular-cookies": "~1.4.2",
    "angular-touch": "~1.4.2",
    "angular-sanitize": "~1.4.2",
    "angular-messages": "~1.4.2",
    "angular-ui-router": "~0.2.15",
    "bootstrap-sass": "~3.3.5",
    "angular-bootstrap": "~0.13.4",
    "malarkey": "yuanqing/malarkey#~1.3.1",
    "angular-toastr": "~1.5.0",
    "moment": "~2.10.6",
    "animate.css": "~3.4.0",
    "angular": "~1.4.2",
    "lodash": "^4.13.1",
    "angular-moment": "^0.10.3",
    "angularLocalStorage": "ngStorage#^0.3.2",
    "ngstorage": "^0.3.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "~1.4.2"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "bootstrap-sass": {
      "main": [
        "assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap.scss",
        "assets/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot",
        "assets/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg",
        "assets/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf",
        "assets/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff",
        "assets/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2"
      ]
    },
    "moment": {
      "main": [
          "min/moment-with-locales.min.js"
      ]
    }
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "angular": "~1.4.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: After this, you still have to declare/set the moment locale before outputting a date, right?

Comment: Of course :) This just ensures you have the translated phrases available so you can switch to another language (on the fly)

Answer (score 3):

I'm using angular2-moment, but usage must be similar.

```
import { MomentModule } from "angular2-moment";
import moment = require("moment");

export class AppModule {

  constructor() {
    moment.locale('ru');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For me, there are some changes to make(ver. 2.20)

1. You set locale with `moment.locale('de')`, and you create a new object representing the date of now by `moment()` (note the parenthesis) and then `format('LLL')` it. The parenthesis is important.

So that means:

```
moment.locale('de');
var now = moment();
now.format('LLL');
```

2. Also, remember to use `moment-with-locale.js`. The file contains all locale info and has a larger file size. Download the `locale` folder is not enough. If necessary, change the name to be `moment.js`. Django just refuses to load `moment-with-locale.js` in my case.

EDIT:
It turned out that renaming the file is not necessary. I just forgot to invoke it in the page so Django does not think loading it is necessary, so my fault.

Answer (score 2):

Please try:

import moment from '**moment/moment**'; 
import 'moment/locale/es';

I found the solution from https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/117997/c%C3%B3mo-utilizar-momentjs-con-fechas-en-espa%C3%B1ol

Comment: For some reason, this is the only version that worked for me out of all those old answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Whoops slip of the pen. I'd solve this:
`var moment = function(x) { return moment(x).locale('de'); }` The other ways don't really seem to stick/hold under conditions (for me).

Answer (score 1):

For those working in asynchronous environments, `moment` behaves unexpectedly when loading locales on demand.

Instead of

```
await import('moment/locale/en-ca');
moment.locale('en-ca');
```

reverse the order

```
moment.locale('en-ca');
await import('moment/locale/en-ca');
```

It seems like the locales are loaded into the current selected locale, overriding any previously set locale information. So switching the locale first, then loading the locale information does not cause this issue.

Answer (score 1):

To change the locale using moment (version later then 2.8.0) perform below steps.

1. load moment locale files in index.html as below
   `<script src="../node_modules/moment/locale/it.js"></script>`
2. Set locale as required - `moment.locale('it')`;
3. Now `moment.locale()` will return "it"
4. You can use moment with any language like - [JavaScript](https://www.qfles.com/interview-question/java-script-interview-questions), [Angular](https://www.qfles.com/interview-question/angular-interview-questions), node etc.

Answer (score 0):

First Call , p5.js and moment-with-locales.js and then do code like below and you will get your result.

In this result I have showed Month Name in different language :)

Check code please :

```js
     var monthNameEnglish = moment().locale('en-gb').format('MMMM');
    document.getElementById('monthNameEnglish').innerHTML =  monthNameEnglish;
    
    
         var monthNameGerman = moment().locale('de').format('MMMM');
    document.getElementById('monthNameGerman').innerHTML =  monthNameGerman;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>P5.js and Moment.js</title>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.16/p5.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.4/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
    
    <h3>English Version Month Name</h3>
    
    <p id="monthNameEnglish"></p>
    
    <h3> German Version Month Name</h3>
    
    <p id="monthNameGerman"></p>
        
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's the reason for importing p5.js? I don't think it's related

Comment: @Andra why you think it is not related ? Please answer it ?

Comment: @Andra, you put a negative review , but even you don't know the answer ?

Answer (score 0):

We can use moment.locale() method to pass your own language ex. I'm using window.navigator.language (ex.en-US)  to pass lange at run time.

```
const formatDate = date => moment(date).locale(window.navigator.language).format('LL')
```