# Get week day in portuguese language from date in moment js

Tags: angularjs, momentjs, angular-moment

This is my code

```
$scope.getWeekDayShort = function(date) {
                moment().locale('pt-br');
                return moment(date, "D_M_YYYY").format('ddd');
            }
```

it returns name of weekday in **english** but need **portuguese** weekday name

If I pass **1_1_2015** it returns **Thu**

How can I get weekday name in portuguese?

**EDIT**

```
moment.locale('pt-br');
console.log(JSON.stringify(moment.months())) // ["janeiro","fevereiro","março","abril","maio","junho","julho","agosto","setembro","outubro","novembro","dezembro"]
moment.locale('en');
console.log(JSON.stringify(moment.months())); // ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"]
```

I have included **moment-with-locales.min.js** file which includes all supported language data and it work good with upper code. So why it not works with week name ?

Comment: Have you loaded a locale for this? [By default, Moment.js comes with English locale strings. If you need other locales, you can load them into Moment.js for later use.](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/) Make sure that you use [moment+locales.js](http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-locales.js)

Answer (score 9):

Try this ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17493309/how-do-i-change-the-language-of-moment-js)):

```
moment(date, "D_M_YYYY").locale('pt-br').format('ddd')
```

Might be worth it to log an issue on [the GitHub page](https://github.com/moment/moment), I think your code should work or the docs should be improved.