# Moment.js - I can't change the date to "pt-br" (ReactJS)

Tags: reactjs, date, momentjs

I'm making a calendar in Portuguese on ReactJS.

Despite being something simple, I'm not able to change my library date "moment.js" to be in the portuguese language (brazil).

Already tried code:

```
<strong>{moment(currentDate).locale('pt-br').format('LLLL')}</strong>
```

But I don't work, it keeps bringing the date in English.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UU7i.png): [image: Date in English]

This is the date format code:

```
const [currentDate, setCurrentDate] = useState(new Date())

<Col>
 <strong>{moment(currentDate).format('LLLL')}</strong>
</Col>
```

How do I make the date stay in Portuguese(Brazil)?

Comment: Related, maybe it will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28110282/get-week-day-in-portuguese-language-from-date-in-moment-js

Comment: @squillman No help, sad.

Answer (score 5):

I just decided to import the location:

```
import 'moment/locale/pt-br'
```

and add code:

```
moment.locale('pt-br')
```

Comment: does not work!!!

Answer (score 1):

You need import your location like that:

import 'moment/locale/pt'

```js
`// import moment from 'moment'
// import 'moment/locale/pt'`



const App = () => {
  return (
    <h1>{moment(new Date()).locale('pt').format('LLLL')}</h1>
  )
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
      <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.4/locale/pt-br.min.js" integrity="sha512-1IpxmBdyZx3okPiZ14mzw6+pOGa690uDmcdjqvT310Kwv3NRcjvL/aOtoSprEyvkDdAb7ZtM2um6KrLqLOY97w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>


<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to use 'pt-br' like this:

```
import 'moment/locale/pt-br'
import moment from 'moment'
```

and it was not working in a React project with Typescript.

I got to fix it this way:

```
import 'moment/dist/locale/pt-br'
```

Just add the folder 'dist' while you're importing the language.
I hope everything works accordingly.