# Is there any way to shorten the Livestamp.js time from '10 minutes ago' to '10m ago'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs, livestamp.js

It could be achieved by editing the `defaultRelativeTime` variable in the `moment.js` file from this:

```
var defaultRelativeTime = {
    future : 'in %s',
    past   : '%s ago',
    s  : 'a few seconds',
    m  : 'a minute',
    mm : '%d minutes',
    h  : 'an hour',
    hh : '%d hours',
    d  : 'a day',
    dd : '%d days',
    M  : 'a month',
    MM : '%d months',
    y  : 'a year',
    yy : '%d years'
};
```

To this:

```
 var defaultRelativeTime = {
        future : 'in %s',
        past   : '%s ago',
        s  : 'a few seconds',
        m  : '1m',
        mm : '%dm',
        h  : '1h',
        hh : '%dh',
        d  : '1D',
        dd : '%dD',
        M  : '1M',
        MM : '%dM',
        y  : '1Y',
        yy : '%dY'
    };
```

But is there any other way in which it could be done WITHOUT modifying the `moment.js` file?

Comment: Maybe using a specific "locale"? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17493309/how-do-i-change-the-language-of-moment-js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can customize the relative time format for your locale using [updateLocale](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/relative-time/) function. You need to pass the relative time object to it.
In your case:

```
moment.updateLocale('en', {
relativeTime : {
    future : 'in %s',
    past   : '%s ago',
    s  : 'a few seconds',
    m  : '1m',
    mm : '%dm',
    h  : '1h',
    hh : '%dh',
    d  : '1D',
    dd : '%dD',
    M  : '1M',
    MM : '%dM',
    y  : '1Y',
    yy : '%dY'
}});
```

Comment: Yep, that works! Thank you. I don't suppose there's a way to keep both the short and long formats and use them as required?