# Show how much time passed with string date

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, react-native

I making a data and inside of data must have string time. Like :

```
 "createdDate": "27-06-2021 13:10",
 // I dont know did made true or not. 
( In my country its like DD/MM/YYYY by the way. )
```

I need calculate it then i need write like "Its created X ( calculated number ) day/week ago" How can i make it ? thanks for all helps!

Comment: The https://momentjs.com/ library is a very popular library that does exactly what you need

Comment: @GuerricP thanks a lot brother! I will try it now.

Comment: @GuerricP brother its works perfectly! But i have a problem again. Its give results english like " 1 day ago " like that. But i need make it Turkish. Is it possible do it ?

Comment: Yes this library supports a wide variety of locales, turkish included hopefully

Comment: @GuerricP Yes in bottom i saw turkish too. But how can i use it turkish in code ? In my project when i wrote : 
`<p>{moment("10052021", "DDMMYYYY").fromNow()}</p>` its giving english result.

Comment: Okay i found solution Thanks for all! For same problem , solution (for me ) : https://stackoverflow.com/a/44864001/15600988