# How to change moment locale in Reactjs when App renders

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

I asked the same question before but there was some confusion.
Actually my question is - I have `Reactjs` application .The application has a Arabic version and English version. And in the application i am using `moment.js`to format the timestamp.when the App renders ,I am storing a language variable in `localstorage` ,i want what  the value of that will be it should apply on `moment.locale`.

How can I implement this.

```js
useEffect (() => {
    const language = localstorage.getItem ("Lang");
    if(language==="ar")
    {
        moment.locale("ar")
    }
    else
    {
        moment.locale("en")
    }
}, [])
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I change the language of moment.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17493309/how-do-i-change-the-language-of-moment-js)

Comment: Hey it seems like your code should work fine, but you also need to import locale.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski it's working but after refreshing application

Comment: Konrad Linkowski it's working but not intialy , when i refresh application then it works

Comment: So probably the locale is set correctly, you just have some dates that depended on moment and you don't update them for some reason