# How use Momentjs in React Native

Tags: react-native, momentjs

Hi how can I use https://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/ in react native ? I exactly need to know how to change the language on my calendar.

Now I have name mounths in Polish but name days I have in english but I nedd  Polish.

```
  import momentPL from 'moment/src/locale/pl' 



    function TermeScreen({ route, navigation }) {
      const { id, title } = route.params;
      const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = useState(new Date());
    
      moment.locale('pl',momentPL );
      let startDate = moment()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```js
import moment from 'moment';

function TermeScreen({ route, navigation }) {
  const { id, title } = route.params;
  const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = useState(new Date());

  let startDate = moment(selectedDate.format("YYYY-MM-DD");
}
```

Comment: I need change name day and mounths from English to Polish langue

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17493309/how-do-i-change-the-language-of-moment-js#:~:text=You'd%20need%20to%20add,that%20locale%20format%20in%20moment. follow this

Comment: Now I have name mounths in Polish but name days I have in english but I nedd Polish.