# How do I output momentjs in arabic?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

I'm trying to show how many time went since the creation on a post! after searching I found that I have to use momentJs.
The time is stored like this:

[image]

And I used this code to show the time

```
{moment.utc(post.createdAt).local().startOf('seconds').fromNow()}
```

and the output is like this:

[image]

now the question is how change the output to arabic language?

Comment: check this https://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/ also this should answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17493309/how-do-i-change-the-language-of-moment-js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add before moment

```
moment.locale('ar_SA'); //for Arabia
```

Answer (score 1):

First I should import the Arabic library

```
import 'moment/locale/ar'
```

then

```
  moment.locale('ar');
  const daysAgo = moment(post.createdAt);
```

And then return it

```
    <span>
      {daysAgo.fromNow()}
    </span>
```